# Decrypting a Base64 string encoded using RSA using Base64 encoded CRT components

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

so I've found myself having to decrypt a string given to me via an API. I know it's been Base64 encoded, and then encrypted with an RSA key (although I'm not sure in what order). I've been given the Modulus, public and private exponents, and the primes. The following code was my (truncated) attempt, and it's throwing me an "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error" on the final line. No idea where to go from here, any help would be appreciated :)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;


public static final String RSAKeyFactory = "RSA";
public static final String RSAKeyAlgorithm = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
public static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

byte[] mod = Base64.getDecoder().decode("3dlF3Frvwmuet+gM/LX8EQBI...");
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1,mod);

byte[] prive64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode("YwTJhmqOS58PJzhhvuREI...");
BigInteger privExp = new BigInteger(1,prive64);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privExp));

byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("VdznCyJeYukJahmHsbge...");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSAKeyAlgorithm);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] plainData = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
```

Cheers

Comment: "although I'm not sure in what order" - that's the first thing to find out. If you're going to reverse a sequence of steps, you need to be absolutely sure of the *original* sequence.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it was Base 64 encoded, and then it was encrypted. And unfortunately the whole encryption process abstracted away in an undocumented API.

Comment: You're almost certainly wrong about that. It was almost certainly encrypted and then base64-encoded. The other way round doesn't make sense.

Comment: Upon reflection of EJP's comment, I would agree with that suggestion. Could you please advise where to go to from here?

Comment: We've no information to go on here. You have some data *that we can't see* that doesn't seem to be working out.